# Make: *** No rule to make target `goddard/udpapp.o', needed by `ns'. Stop

Tags: makefile, ns2

Why am I having this error? Can someone help me with this? I'm using ns2.35. I have tried searching for the solution but can't find it. This is for the goddard streaming application.

```
OBJ_CC = \
tools/random.o tools/rng.o tools/ranvar.o common/misc.o common/timer-handler.o \
.
.
.
.
goddard/udpapp.o goddard/mchannel_proc.o \
goddard/gframe_queue.o goddard/goddard.o goddard/gplayer.o \
@V_STLOBJ@
```

These were the codes that I need to add in the Makefile.in , in order for the application to work.

Please help me. This is for my fyp project.

Comment: perhaps you need to either get rid of the blank line, or add a `\ ` to it so that the additional lines get included in the continuation... As listed above, the content from `goddard/udpapp.o` on is not getting included in `OBJ_CC`...

Comment: but the bottom one got no problem. the 2nd one is not the continuation frm the 1st.

Comment: If the second one is not the continuation of the first, what is it ? It's neither a variable assignment nor a call or command. What is make supposed to do with all these .o files without command or variable assignment ? It's not even a rule.

Comment: there are 2 files related i guess in generating this udpapp.o , the files are udpapp.cc and udpapp.h ... same goes to the gframe_queue and gplayer both have the .cc and .h